# Understanding Jordan blocks all in the same $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$-conjugacy class

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This may be an elementary question and I haven't been able to find if such a question has been asked on Math StackExchange but here it is:

suppose $M$ is an $n\times n$ matrix over $\mathbb{C}$ that is $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$-conjugate to $J$ where $J$ is a Jordan matrix with Jordan blocks 
$$ J = 
\left[ 
\begin{array}{cccc}
J_1 &   0 & \ldots & 0  \\
0   & J_2 & \ldots & 0  \\
0 & 0     & \ddots & 0  \\ 
0 & 0     & \ldots & J_k \\
\end{array} 
\right]
$$ 
where each $J_i$ is of rank $k_i$, all with the same eigenvalue $\lambda$; so 
$$
J_i = \left[
\begin{array}{ccccc} 
\lambda & 1       & 0   & \ldots   & 0 \\ 
0       & \lambda & 1   & \ldots   & 0 \\ 
0       & 0       &\lambda &  \ldots   &\vdots  \\
0       & 0   & 0 & \ddots & 1 \\ 
0       & 0   & 0       & \ldots    & \lambda \\
\end{array} 
\right]. 
$$
Then for any 
$$
J' = \left[ 
\begin{array}{cccc}
J_{\sigma(1)} &   0 & \ldots & 0  \\
0   & J_{\sigma(2)} & \ldots & 0  \\
0 & 0     & \ddots & 0  \\ 
0 & 0     & \ldots & J_{\sigma(k)} \\
\end{array} 
\right]
$$
where $\sigma:\{1,2,\ldots, k\}\rightarrow \{ 1,2,\ldots, k\}$ is injective, 
doesn't there exist $g\in GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ so that $gJg^{-1}=J'$? Basically, 
couldn't we always permute these Jordan blocks under the $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$-conjugation action?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we could. This is not specific to Jordan blocks. Quite generally, to any permutation $\pi$ there corresponds a permutation matrix $\Pi$ with $\Pi_{ij}=\delta_{i\pi(j)}$ with determinant $\pm1$. This permutation matrix permutes the rows of a matrix according to $\pi$ upon left-multiplication and the columns of a matrix according to $\pi^{-1}$ upon right-multiplication, so $\Pi J\Pi^{-1}$ permutes both the rows and the columns of $J$ according to $\pi$. Your rearrangement of the Jordan blocks is a specific case of such a permutation of the rows and columns of a matrix.

Comment: @math-visitor: You're welcome!